# Удаление записей sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не могу разобраться с ошибкой. Есть две таблицы Cars и #cars_v , в таблицах есть столбец link, по которому необходимо удалить из таблицы cars все строки ,где поле link имеет равное поле в #cars_v.

```
    DELETE FROM Cars WHERE Cars.link IN (SELECT link FROM #cars_v);
```

Comment: *не могу разобраться с ошибкой* А текст сообщения об ошибке - тайна?

Comment: после этого удаления следует вставка и при вставке пишет что не удается вставить повторяющееся значение

Comment: Ну вот можно по тексту вопроса об этом догадаться, а? что Вы ещё "забыли" рассказать? Мой Вам совет - откорректируйте вопрос и опишите ВЕСЬ ПРОЦЕСС. Структура таблиц, наполнение таблиц (по 2-3 записи), удаление-добавление (точные тексты запросов), сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Возможно у вас используется трансзакция. Вы не можете добавить запись, до тех пор пока удаление не будет произведено "окончательно" (потому что если будет обрыв - то из-за RollBack появятся дубли). Возможно надо разбить удаление и вставку на два действия. Возможно между действиями нужно вставить Commit.

Comment: А так же, возможно в процессе вы всётаки вставляете "дубли".